# Where is the new NHibernate Core Linq?

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I'm running NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 but there's no Query() method off my session...

Which version of NHibernate introduces linq into the core?

I'm still running on the old Contrib Linq.

I've just upgraded to the latest stable release of Sharp Architecture which makes it difficult to upgrade individual components (e.g. NHibernate) off the trunk because of dependency nightmares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate 3 is supposed to introduce Linq into the Core libraries.  Until then you need to include the [external linq provider](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx) *(which it looks like you're aware of)*.  It's part part of NHContrib and can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/#node-16-0).

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [WhoCanHelpMe](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/).  it uses s#arp at it's core but has a LinqRepository.